# consolidating data with non-unique ID number in SQL- conditional summation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using microsoft SQL server. have a table with orderIDs, but unfortunately these IDs are not unique. Each sales transaction has an idea (often duplicate), and a the total amount spent by the customer. I would like to use a SQL query to return unique ID#s and the sum of their transactions.

right now it looks like this:

-ID #  -----------   SalesTotal

1     ----------------$5

1       ------------  $10

2        ----------- $20

I would like it to look like this:

ID#   ------   SalesTotal

1     -----------    $15

2       ----------  $20

I'm not sure how to make the sumation within the second column conditional on the contents of the first column.

Answer (score 2):

This just grouping and summing up the total:

```
select [ID], SUM(SalesTotal)
from yourtable
group by [ID]
```